# any open source for android template example for website can use template bootstrap

Tags: android, xamarin.android

For a website, we can use bootstrap to be our template. In android which template we can use? any recommendations for Android templates, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends in what language you are going to program your android app in . If you are going to program in native code you should look templates in Java/Kotlin and for UI Xml. If it is in Xamarin or other hybrid apps you should look what programming language they support .

Comment: I using Xamarin

Comment: I think you should do a google search on Xamarin templates There are some prebuilt apps on this site you can look at https://www.xamarin.com/prebuilt